# My computer crashed while downloading Apple arcade apps, now I can't download them

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, games

I was downloading a bunch of Apple arcade games, and my computer crashed. It is very old, about 8 years this year, and it has been crashing a lot.

It crashed while I was downloading a bunch of games, and I cannot download the games that I was downloading while it crashed.

I can download other games that I had not downloaded before, but when I click on get for games that I was downloading, it does the loading thing where it turns into a spinning circle, but then instead of starting to download, it just turns back into get. No error message, no nothing.

I think it might be something like it still thinks it's downloading the games, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is so much missing here.  You mention “computer” and not a specific Mac or macOS version.  To what computer and OS are you downloading to?  What have you tried to fix the problem?  Have you tried downloading somewhere else (different computer)?  Please [edit] with thiese missing key details

Comment: Please edit this and flag for reopening if it doesn't get votes once you've put in some details. The answer in the linked question would be very good details to add as are the basics above - pick one specific app, one specific macOS version and let us have some items to help you out. Also - note if you powered off the computer and the same error happens immediately after you restart the Mac...